# how to know a input is ime or tsf?

Tags: text-services-framework

i use win7 64bit, local language is chinese.

some input use ime, and some input use tsf.

i want use LoadKeyboardLayout() to active a special keyboard layout sometimes, but when call GetKeyboardLayoutName(), the tsf input and default ime return same keyboard layout "0x00000804"。

so i can't active tsf input use LoadKeyboardLayout(), i know how to active tsf input through ITfInputProcessorProfiles interface.

but how to get current input is ime or tsf?

thanks.

Comment: What is the context of your question?  In particular, are you writing an application, a text service, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

When the *language* changes, TSF will send notifications via [ITfLanguageProfileNotifySink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms628769%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), when the *IME* changes, TSF will send notifications via [ItfActiveLanguageProfileNotifySink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms538491%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).